# EF Core Where Clause throws Exception when Comparing date with datenow

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I have a Query method which is supposed to give me the next matches from today's date till 7 days, given a league ID. So if todays date is 2019-10-11 then it should give me all the sports matches till 2019-10-18.

```
        public IQueryable<MatchDTO> GetMatchesForNextSevenDaysByLeagueAsync(int leagueId)
        {
            var todayDate = DateTime.Now;
            var matches = _context.Matches.Include(e => e.HomeTeam).Include(e => e.AwayTeam).Include(e => e.League).Where(m => m.LeagueId == leagueId).OrderBy(m => m.MatchDate).ThenBy(m => m.Time).Where(m => ((todayDate - m.MatchDate).Days) <=7).Select(m => DTOConverter.ConvertMatchToDTO(m));

            return matches;
        }
```

The call throws an exception:

```
"The LINQ expression 'Where<Match>(\r\n    source: 
ThenBy<Match, DateTime>(\r\n        source: OrderBy<Match, DateTime>(\r\n            
source: Where<Match>(\r\n                source: DbSet<Match>, \r\n                
predicate: (m) => m.LeagueId == (Unhandled parameter: __leagueId_0)), \r\n            
keySelector: (m) => m.MatchDate), \r\n        keySelector: (m) => m.Time), \r\n    
predicate: (m) => m.MatchDate - (Unhandled parameter: __todayDate_1).TotalDays <= 7)' 
could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or 
switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), 
ToList(), or ToListAsync(). 
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."
```

For me it looks like it does not like the way I compare the dates in `.Where(m => ((todayDate - m.MatchDate).Days) <=7)`

I have tried to use client evaluation but it is too slow. Any thoughts on how I could rewrite this so the code would work.

Note that I am using EF Core 3.0

Comment: What about using something like `.Where(m => m.MatchDate < calculatedDayWith7DaysOffset)` (or using `>`)? A simple compare against a constant value will work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by calculatedDayWith7DaysOffset. I am supposed to compare it with today's date. Do you mean to take todays date and give it an offset with + 7 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that line is a little hard to read without having to scroll back and forth so I hope you don't mind that I've reformatted it for my own connivence:

```cs
var matches = _context
    .Matches
    .Include(e => e.HomeTeam)
    .Include(e => e.AwayTeam)
    .Include(e => e.League)
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(m => m.LeagueId == leagueId)
    .OrderBy(m => m.MatchDate)
    .ThenBy(m => m.Time)
    .Where(m => ((todayDate - m.MatchDate).Days) <=7)
    .Select(m => DTOConverter.ConvertMatchToDTO(m));
```

Reading through this I can see that your second `.Where` clause is checking the `.Days` property value of one date minus another. I doubt Entity Framework is able to translate this into valid SQL which is why you're seeing that error.

Is there any reason you can't calculate on the client what date is "valid" and then just let SQL filter the rows as necessary? For example:

`.Where(m => m.MatchDate >= DateTime.Now && <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(7))`

That should get translated into a TSQL `BETWEEN` statement - which is far better than trying to parse the datetimes you have stored to get the day portion and work out if they're a specific number away from a given date.

That said you might want to have a look at the query you've written in general. I'm not quite sure from the snippet you provided why the `.AsQueryable` is necessary - the extension methods you're using accept both `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` natively so you shouldn't have to cast.

I'd also combine the two where clauses before you try and order the result set. Not sure if EF to SQL is clever enough in all cases to optimise this away but it won't hurt! In summary your final query should look something like this:

```cs
var matches = _context
    .Matches
    .Include(e => e.HomeTeam)
    .Include(e => e.AwayTeam)
    .Include(e => e.League)
    .Where(m => 
        m.LeagueId == leagueId 
        && m.MatchDate >= DateTime.Now && <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(7))
    .OrderBy(m => m.MatchDate)
    .ThenBy(m => m.Time)
    .Select(m => DTOConverter.ConvertMatchToDTO(m));
```

Comment: Yeesssss :D. Thanks mate. Progman already mentioned it in the comments so also creds to him, but I will mark your answer as correct. As to the ".AsQueryable" that was a copy paste mistake by me, which I have edited in the question.

Comment: Should also be able to use `EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(todayDate, m.MatchDate) <= 7`. @HadiSalameh, can you [submit an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/new/choose)? EF should just handle your original expression.

Comment: Just to add another data point, I had a simple where clause as well using C# timespan - (t.TimeStamp - '9/23/2021 06:00 -7:00').Seconds - and the call hangs for me.  No exception, just hang.  I switched to the EF.Functions approach and it's working.